# object not showing up in NLA editor

Tags: animation, nla-editor

[image]
if it isn't much trouble could someone tell me how to get my robot and it's actions to show up in the NLA editor again? been trying everything i can think off but it still wont work.

its action's were muted in the nla but the Outliner still says they are there and the dope sheet remembers the actions but the object wont show up in the NLA editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the NLA Filters menu icon make sure all choices are selected ... dark color.

[image]